# Unable to login to Jenkins after enabling matrix based authentication in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I enabled matrix based authentication in Jenkins and tried logging in...but Jenkins was throwing invalid login error even after entering correct credentials. I tried logging by using the user names that I had added in the matrix based authentication field but it throws error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access your jenkins by modifying config.xml in JENKINS_HOME(usually /var/lib/jenkins).

```
 <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

Change true>false and restart jenkins . You will be able to login.

- Then configure your auth settings properly. Can't help you with that, need more info about security configuration.